# How To Remove Default Toast When Using Android Email Intent?

Tags: android, email

I'm currently using an email intent to allow users to send an email from the application. However, I've come across a strange problem I've not had before: I'm getting a default toast that says 'Sending message..." which does not appear with my other email activity.

Has anyone had this issue before or know how to fix it?

```
void SelectImage()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent
            (Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    try {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.d("Result Code:", Integer.toString(resultCode));
        Log.d("Data Results:", data.toString());
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Photo Submission From Android");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"enroq@kairyt.com"});
            intent.setType("image/*");
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send E-mail"));
        }
    }

    catch (Exception e) { Log.d("Exception:", e.toString()); e.printStackTrace(); }
}
```

Comment: Please post your working code

Comment: Code added. Sorry about that. First time it was like, your post is all code.

Comment: I think the toast is inbuilt in the default gmail app

Comment: Hmm, you could be right. I just didn't remember seeing it before. That would make sense, though.

Comment: Yeah, it appears to be built in. I'd still like to remove it :P